# Using .text() to add html elements

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the "inner HTML" of an element on my webpage and am doing it using jquery. However, when it runs, the elements appear on the page instead of acting as elements. For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('span' , 'h2').text( "<b>Some</b><br>new text." );
});
```

Changes the text of the `span` to `<span>&lt;b&gt;Some&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;new text.</span>` when I want it to be `<span><b>Some</b><br>new text.</span>`

Is this possible to do? If so how would i do it?

Comment: use html() instead of text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` only sets/gets the inner text of elements, not the HTML. Use `html()` instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('span' , 'h2').html( "<b>Some</b><br>new text." );
});
```

Comment: Perfect! this worked wonderfully. Only thing now is i cannot, for the life of me, get this to work with a hover or click event. Anything for that? This is what i have:

`$("span" , "h2").click(
 $(function() {
  $(this).html('<b>Some</b><br>new text.')
 })
);`

Comment: Can you show a proper example of your HTML? That will allow for a demo too. You reference a span in a h2 but do not show the h2 element.

Comment: This is the html:
`<h2 class="aboutPeople"><span>Lee<span class='spacer'></span><br><span class='spacer'></span>Atkinson</span></h2>`

Basically, on the hover i want to be able to change the text in between the span to something else.